# Problem with RandomColor

Tags: graphics, manipulate, evaluation, random

I was trying to produce a little animation with `Manipulate`, where a Regular Poligon  with N sides  is displayed  behind the previous polygon with N-1 sides , each one with a `RandomColor`.
I wrote this piece of code:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Reverse[
   Style[RegularPolygon[#], RandomColor[]] & /@ Range[3, l, 1]]] , {l,
   3, 8, 1}]
```

The problem is that the color keeps changing even for the Polygons on the front. How can I avoid this? Once the color for a polygon is fixed it should not change anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach is to use `SeedRandom` to block the randomness of `RandomColor` when Seed keeps the same. But the drawback of this method is that in multiple runs, the color will keep the same.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Reverse[
   Style[RegularPolygon[#], SeedRandom[#]; RandomColor[]] & /@ 
    Range[3, l, 1]]], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
```

So, to aviod this, a yet simple method is to set `SeedRandom`'s content a bit more random:

```
k = RandomInteger[{1,1000}];

Manipulate[Graphics[Reverse[
   Style[RegularPolygon[#], SeedRandom[k #]; RandomColor[]] & /@ 
    Range[3, l, 1]]], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
```

Then everything will be fine!

Comment: oh thanks, i am relatively new to mathematica but i am really enjoying it.   update:nvm it was wrong

Answer (score 7):

You should only generate the colors once.

```
With[{colors = RandomColor[8 - 2]},
  Manipulate[
    Graphics[{{colors[[# - 2]], RegularPolygon[#]} & /@ Range[n, 3, -1]}], 
    {n, 3, 8, 1, SetterBar}]]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 4):

Here is my revision

```
color = RandomColor[6];
Manipulate[
           Graphics[{color[[# - 2]], RegularPolygon[#]} & /@ Range[l, 3, -1]], 
           {l, 3, 8, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: how would you modify the code if you  don't want to  preeventively store the entire set of colors before using manipulate? suppose I set the upper limit of manipulate at 5, , the other  colors stored are wasted

Comment: This seems to duplicate my earlier answer. What value does it add over my answer?

Comment: i upvoted both.  i asked him a question because i saw his message was just 1 minute old and i thought he would be still online.